# Windows 8 Development, Run/Debug to local fails, but Run/Debug to simulator works

Tags: windows-8

I've installed Win8 Preview on my Lenovo w520 that gives me two remote screens and the laptop screen as well. Metro always comes up on the laptop screen (I don't know how to control it).  Even when I create a brand new app (from blank) and just put a simple `<p>hi</p>` on the `default.html`. I get nothing besides my splash screen, then a black screen on my laptop.

However, when I run in the Win 8 Simulator, I get correct behavior (below image).

[image: Correct beaviour]

Answer (score 0):

When this happens I go through a dance of trying different things in this order:

1) restart windows explorer from the task manager
2) kill the unnammed processes that appear in task manager
3) restart visual studio
4) reboot the PC